# I'm getting error that DelegateAuthenticationProvider and MeRequestBuilder are not found in the graphService client I use to read Microsoft 365 mail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, pop3, microsoft365

Since Microsoft has switched from basic auth to bearer auth as of 2023, I cannot perform mail reading operations. I am trying to read with GraphServiceClient, but I am getting the below mentioned errors,can you help?

*- CS0246-->The type or namespace name 'DelegateAuthenticationProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

- CS1061--> 'MeRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Request' and no accessible extension method 'Request' accepting a first argument of type 'MeRequestBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
namespace GraphTest.Helpers
{
    public class GraphHelper
    {
        public static async Task<CachedUser> GetUserDetailsAsync(string accessToken)
        {
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    async (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                    }));

            var user = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                .Select(u => new
                {
                    u.DisplayName,
                    u.Mail,
                    u.UserPrincipalName
                })
                .GetAsync();

            return new CachedUser
            {
                Avatar = string.Empty,
                DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
                Email = string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Mail) ?
                    user.UserPrincipalName : user.Mail
            };  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: You are probably using Graph SDK v5. There are breaking changes. I would recommend to follow upgrade guide: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md

Answer (score 4):

The v5 SDK had a lot of changes, you can read about it here :

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md

### Authentication

In place of the DelegateAuthenticationProvider, custom authentication flows can be done creating an implementation of IAccessTokenProvider, and using with the BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider from the Kiota abstractions as follows

```
public class TokenProvider : IAccessTokenProvider
{
    public Task<string> GetAuthorizationTokenAsync(Uri uri, Dictionary<string, object> additionalAuthenticationContext = default,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var token = "token";
        // get the token and return it in your own way
        return Task.FromResult(token);
    }

    public AllowedHostsValidator AllowedHostsValidator { get; }
}
```

Then create the GraphServiceClient as follows

```
var authenticationProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(new TokenProvider());
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
```

### Removal of Request() from the fluent API

In previous versions, of the SDK, calls involved the calling of Request() in the request API as follows

```
var user = await graphServiceClient
.Me
.Request()  // this is removed
.GetAsync();
```

A similar call in the V5 will have the Request() section removed to be called as below.

```
var user = await graphServiceClient
.Me
.GetAsync();
```